# git show last few commits leading back to a merge-base

Tags: git, git-history-graph

Two branches diverged a long time ago (e.g. devel and master). I'd like to show the history either side of that divergence point, e.g. +/-10 commits. (This is to decide how to recapture the old branches give a change in naming convention)

It is easy to locate the merge-base (`git merge-base devel master`), and to show the 10 commits before that (e.g. `git log --oneline -10 $(git merge-base devel master)`).

But I'm not sure how to locate the points 10 commits before (more recent than) the merge-base to limit the commit range displayed (e.g. with show-branch).

Is there a way to the n'th more recent commit along a given line of development?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you just want grep's context option.

```
git log devel master --no-abbrev-commit --oneline --date-order \
| grep -10 $(git merge-base devel master)
```

If you want the graph structure drawn for those, git log has to print some lines without commits to keep everything connected properly and that will mess with your counts.  So get the raw commit ids first and then tell log to graph them all explicitly:

```
git rev-list --date-order devel master \
| grep -10 $(git merge-base devel master) \
| xargs git log -21 --graph --decorate --oneline
```

Comment: That's a pretty solid command line. Thank's for crafting that.  I'd been hoping perhaps for a hidden --before= option to complement the --more option to `git show-branch`;-)

Comment: np, ... `show-branch`'s `--more` doesn't do the `--before` thing either, context like this seems like a helpful thing to show but since log output gets fed through your pager anyway you can just `/` to the right commit and get however much you want.  I fixed a typo and added date-order to the revlist.

Comment: p.s. I confess I really don't understand the (common here on s.o.) desire to have command options for things perfectly ordinary tools can already do for you. That leads to every tool importing all the general-purpose tools, it seems to me like pointless duplication and a waste.

Comment: I do know the feeling;-), but obviously things I think are common (i.e. my needs) I think should obviously be available as a nice option - so surely there must be one already available... (the classic projection bias fallacy). In this case it's also I've been in a Windows environment for years so the bash/Linux scripting takes that extra bit of [my finite cognitive] effort, so its a trade-off. Either-way, thanks for the cli scripts.